# How to log ansible_python_interpreter failed IPs using Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, service-discovery

I'm not looking for a solution to fix the below python interpreter discovery failed error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts]
fatal: [123.123.123.123]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, 
  "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\n", 
  "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
  "rc": 127
```

Instead, what i need is to log IPs where python discovery failed.

Below is my plabook where i'm able to log failed, telnet and failed ssh from my ansible host. However, I wish to also log failed python discovery.

Below is my playbook.

```
- name: Play 3- check nodes
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

   - name: Check all port numbers are accessible from current host
     include_tasks: /app/checkssh/innertelnet.yml
     with_items: "{{ groups['all_hosts'] }}"

cat innertelnet.yml

---
       - wait_for:
           host: "{{ item }}"
           port: 22
           state: started
           delay: 0
           timeout: 2
         ignore_errors: yes
         register: netstatoutput

       - raw: "echo telnet failed on IP {{ item }}"
         delegate_to: localhost
         when: netstatoutput.failed == 'True'

       - name: Check ssh connectivity
         ignore_errors: yes
         raw: "ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@{{ item }} echo success"
         register: sshcheck

       - raw: "echo ssh failed on IP {{ item }}"
         delegate_to: localhost
         when: not netstatoutput.failed and sshcheck is unreachable
```

For successful ssh connectivity how can i detect if python_interpreter was discovered by ansible on the target host ?

Thus, I'm looking for the below:

```
   - raw: "Python could not be discovered on IP {{ item }}"
     delegate_to: localhost
     when: <>
```

How to suppress the fatal error of discover_python_interpreter and log all the IPs using `raw` module where it is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to check Python interpreter discovery is to actually run a task on the remote host.

The first thing you need to do is to disable automatic fact gathering, since this requires that Ansible is able to run the `setup` module on your target hosts:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
```

With fact gathering disabled, you have more control over things. For example, we can do something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
      - ping:
        register: check
      rescue:
      - delegate_to: localhost
        when: >
            "No python interpreters found" in check.warnings|default([])|join("\n")
        debug:
          msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} has no python interpreter"
```

If I run this against two hosts, `node0` without Python and `node1` with Python, we see:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [ping] ********************************************************************
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
ok: [node1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [node0 -> localhost] => {
    "msg": "node0 has no python interpreter"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
node0                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0   
node1                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```